# How to write a variable into a file?

Tags: robotframework

I would like to store `${Username}` value in an output file:

E.g. If `${Username}` equals `0401190926729000`, this value will be stored in a file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an proposal:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  String

*** test cases ***
write_variable_in_file
  ${Username} =  Generate Random String  1  abc
  log to console   ${Username}
  run keyword if  '${Username}' == 'a'   write_variable_in_file  ${Username}

*** Keywords ***
write_variable_in_file
  [Arguments]  ${variable}
  Create File  ${EXECDIR}/file_with_variable.txt  ${variable}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply. And if i want to add next value, just have to use Append To File. Am i right?

Comment: yes, do the "create file" only once in the beginning and then "Append To File" (can you set the question as answered if that is OK for you?).

Comment: really helpful. Vote Uy Tin.