# How to Append value separated by new line to file?

Tags: robotframework

According to tip i get here: [How to write a variable into a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397198/how-to-write-a-variable-into-a-file)
i use Append To File command to add new number to file. Unfortunately append adds in the same line, so it looks like:

```
'0421085414373000''0421085453944000'...
```

Maybe someone of you knows how to append new number separated by new line to file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `${\n}` at the end of the string to get a newline character.

See [Operating-system variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#operating-system-variables) in Robot User Guide.

Answer (score -1):

add `${\n}` at the end of your variable

Variables

```
${Number1}      4356674547645765${\n}
```

Keywords

```
input text      ${NotesEditBox}        ${Number1}
```

your cursor will be automatically on the next line for your next number