# How to store database value in text file. Select statement return null

Tags: sql, database, select, text-files, robotframework

Hi I am quite new to robot framework, and I am trying to obtain database result via select statement and store into a .txt file.

I am able to connect to my database and execute my select statement, however the return value for my select statement is 'NONE'.

```
Execute Sql String SELECT BTH_N FROM BAS_BERTH_APPLN_MASTER WHERE ABBR_VSL_M='APL';
```

Any idea on how to solve the select statement issue and how I can store that value in a .txt file?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably not the root cause, but are certain that you even have non NULL data in the table?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, very sure that there is no null data in the table

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.... the return vale is 'NONE' not 'NULL'

Comment: Where does the `Execute Sql String` keyword come from. Is it one you wrote, or is it from a library?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an SQL Script?
If not, you can use the Query Keyword. 
https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Query

```
${result}=    Query    SELECT BTH_N FROM BAS_BERTH_APPLN_MASTER WHERE ABBR_VSL_M='APL'
```

A solution to store the result in a .txt file : [How to write a variable into a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397198/how-to-write-a-variable-into-a-file)